# Code not executing after function inside of Switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement, codeblocks

The following code in Case 'Y' or 'y' the function randStats() is called and after the function returns I need it to execute the code below the function call in the Switch case, but it is not doing so. This may be a compiler issue, because I've had issues in the past with Codeblocks where new code seems to be completely ignored, while some other isn't.

Here is a paste of the function itself that is called by the switch below: http://ideone.com/Rx3Ig9

Note: As far as I can tell this isn't a coding issue, it's an issue with code being completely ignored.

```
// newchar.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"
#include "randstats.h"
#include "newchar.h"

int new_character()
{

std::cout << "\n\nCreating new character...";
std::cout << "\n\nClaim an alias for your character: ";
std::cin >> player.alias;

char x;

std::cout << "You have chosen " << player.alias << "\n";
std::cout << "Is this correct? [y/n]: ";
std::cin >> x;

switch(x)
{
case 'y':
case 'Y':
    std::cout << "\nInserting " << player.alias << " into this hapless world of strife...";
    std::cout << "\n\nRandomizing stats...\n" << std::endl;
    randStats(); // randomize stats

    //print new character information
    std::cout << "Alias: " << player.alias << "Level: " << player.current_level << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stats: " << player.str << "STR " << player.dex << "DEX " << player.con << "CON " << player.intel << "INT " << player.wis << "WIS " << player.cha << "CHA " << std::endl;
    break;
case 'n':
case 'N':
    std::cout << "Aborting...\n";
    break;
default:
    break;

}

//update the database
//do it


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `randStats()` is returning? That seems like the only explanation.

Comment: In the randstats.cpp file I linked from ideone here http://ideone.com/Rx3Ig9

Comment: See functions `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` so you can convert to one case and make 2 comparisons instead of 4.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger, to see what happens after `randStats()`?

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with the debugger, put an output command after your switch, make sure you end it with << endl; (so it flushes).  See if you even make it out of that switch statement.

Comment: You may be processing *newlines* left over in the buffer in the `randStats` function and therefore, stuck in `randStats` forever.

Comment: Not trying to be insulting by pointing out someting so obvious, but are you sure you're sending enough information to std input?  I mean if you're sure your randstats() works and I've already shown your switch logic is okay.  You could just be stuck waiting for input.

Comment: No, it returns to the menu as it should. It just skips the few lines of console output. Completely ignores it.

Comment: @ChrisCM I added the line after the switch. It is ignoring that line also. It's returning to the menu after creating the "new character" which the switch handles, so I don't know how it could be ignoring these lines after the switch and after calling the function the switch is in (both), when it's returning to the menu which happens after they are both done. I've had issues a lot with CodeBlocks just completely ignoring new lines of code. At least, I have good reason to believe it's doing it.

Comment: Issue fixed (noted under answer)

Comment: @ChrisGrooms, if your issue is solved, either mark the right answer as solved (check mark under the answer's score) or if you figured it out on your own, write an answer for your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Line 49 in randstats.cpp is

```
// remaining_points - x;
```

It should be uncommented and fixed as:

```
remaining_points -= x;
```

with the equal sign.

Otherwise, it loops forever.

Comment: It has never "looped forever" for me.

Comment: Ah ha. It seems because I called the function from the switch, then called another function from a switch inside of the function that was called, it never returns to the original switch and executes any code after it... I was misled by someone it seems. I removed the function call from the switch that's inside the function that was called and now it simply executes the code below all the function calls. If that makes any sense. So be aware, it doesn't return to the switch and do anything below a function call.